# Sort a result in groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with multiple duplicates by name for different users.I get the duplicates in the table using a query like

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM [Database].[dbo].[table] t1
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT [Name]
   FROM [Database].[dbo].[table]
   GROUP BY [Name]
   HAVING COUNT(*) >1 ) t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
```

From this I get the duplicates by name from the table. My question is this, how do I get the results sorted in groups like so

```
Name             Customer

John             Daydream
John             Daydream
Peter            Daydream
Peter            Daydream
Peter            Daydream
Amber            Fly_co
Amber            Fly_co
Jackie           Fly_co
Jackie           Fly_co
```

Comment: ... ORDER BY t1.Customer, t1.Name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        SELECT t1.*
        FROM [Database].[dbo].[table] t1
        INNER JOIN
          (SELECT [Name]
                   FROM [Database].[dbo].[table]
                   GROUP BY [Name]  
                   HAVING COUNT(*) >1 ) t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
 ORDER BY t1.Customer, t1.Name
```

Comment: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 SELECT t1.*
    FROM [Database].[dbo].[table] t1
    INNER JOIN
      ( SELECT [Name]
       FROM [Database].[dbo].[table]
       GROUP BY t1. [Name]
       HAVING COUNT(*) >1 ) t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
    ORDER BY t1.Customer, t1.Name
```

Comment: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Updated in my answer

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, but i am getting an error when trying to execute this.

Comment: ...seems I pressed "Enter" too early. The multi-part identifier "t1.Name" could not be bound.

Comment: @MartinNikolaevIvanov there is one space removed b/w `by` and `t1`